# TypeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

In my models.py I have the following class:

```
class AvailabilityTypes():
    STUDYING = 'STUDYING'
    WORKING = 'WORKING'
    SEARCHING = 'SEARCHING'
    FREELANCER = 'FREELANCER'

    types = (
        (STUDYING, 'Estudando'),
        (WORKING, 'Trabalhando'),
        (SEARCHING, 'Procurando por emprego'),
        (FREELANCER, 'Freelancer')
    )

    def get_types(self):
        return self.types.all()
```

And I want to show that options in a Django Form. In my forms.py file I have the following piece of code:

```
from django import forms
from .models import AvailabilityTypes

[...]

availability = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=(AvailabilityTypes.types)
        )
    )
```

But I get the error `TypeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object is not iterable`. What am I doing wrong? Also, if I try using:

```
availability = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=(AvailabilityTypes.get_types())
        )
    )
```

I get the error `TypeError: get_types() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.`

I'm new to Django and Python, I could use some light. Thank you.

Comment: your model class `AvailabilityTypes` needs to extend `django.db.models.Model` Your model's field needs to be `type = models.CharField(arguments)`. Then in forms you can extend forms.ModelForm and then no need to worry about creating widgets manually.

Comment: No, AvailabilityTypes appears to just be a holding class for `types`, not a model; it seems a bit pointless, and `get_types` completely so.

Comment: Thank you @VaibhavVishal I'll definately try this. My supervisor told me not to, but I see that maybe that's the only way around.

Comment: @danielroseman yes maybe that's the case. @ Barbara You should just define a tuple outside any class with all choices. Also the first element of each tuple is a variable I guess because maybe you if you wanted to change it later easily. But first string of the tuple is what gets saved in database and second is human readable format. Changing the first one might mess up your database, try not to change it. You can change the human readable string whenever you want. That's why django provides this way to save choices.

Comment: Be sure to extend `ModelForm` in your forms class. That's the whole point of using frameworks like Django, do more in less code and deliver faster. Maybe your supervisor asked you not to do that because you are new and he wanted you to learn from basics, in that case I don't disagree with him. But once you have understood all the concepts always try to extends classes provided by Django to minimize the code you write.

Comment: In case you have to do it the way you are currently doing then I am writing an answer with all corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sol 1. Fix your current code**

First fix your method `get_types()`:

```
class AvailabilityTypes():
...
# Above this Same as your code

def get_types(self):
    return self.types  # You need to return just types, it is a tuple, it doesn't has an attribute all(). In Django we usually use all() in querysets.
```

Now fix the form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import AvailabilityTypes

at_obj = AvailabilityTypes()  # Create an object of class AvailabilityTypes

[...]  # Guessing form class starts here

availability = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.ChoiceField(
        # choices=AvailabilityTypes.get_types()  # You can't call a class's method on that class, you call it on that class's object
        choices=(at_obj.get_types())  # Call the method on object of the class not class itself
    )
)
```

**Sol 2. Don't create unnecessary class**

In models.py there is no need to create a class to hold types. you can do this:

```
...
# All your imports go above this
# These four variables are pointless in my opinion, but I will leave them be
STUDYING = 'STUDYING'
WORKING = 'WORKING'
SEARCHING = 'SEARCHING'
FREELANCER = 'FREELANCER'

# types is an constant so it should follow uppercase naming style
TYPES = (  
    (STUDYING, 'Estudando'),
    (WORKING, 'Trabalhando'),
    (SEARCHING, 'Procurando por emprego'),
    (FREELANCER, 'Freelancer')
)

# Create your models Here
...
```

Now in your forms.py:

```
...
from .models import TYPES  # Import the tuple from models

[...]

availability = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPES)  # Use the imported tuple directly here
)
```

**Sol 3. Use model form(simplest and easiest)**

In your models:

```
from django.db import models

# types is an constant so it should follow uppercase naming style
TYPES = (  
    ('STUDYING', 'Estudando', ),
    ('WORKING', 'Trabalhando', ),
    ('SEARCHING', 'Procurando por emprego', ),
    ('FREELANCER', 'Freelancer', ),  # Unlike other languages your last element can have a trailing comma too, its optional but still do that. I has some advantages which I am not gonna explain here
)

# Create your models Here
class MyModel(models.Model):
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=63, choices=TYPES)
    # Other fields of your model
    ...
```

Now in your forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('availability', )  # add other fields of your models too in the tuple
```

And that's it. You are done, use your forms in views. Django will take care of showing right choices, validating them, showing relevent error messages and saving the valid data in database.